# How to convert this SQL query to Laravel Syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

Here my MySQL query (work in phpMyAdmin) :

```sql
    SELECT waktu_kerusakan, workcenter, COUNT(workcenter) AS jumlah_repair 
    FROM repair WHERE year(waktu_kerusakan)='2019'  GROUP BY workcenter , 
    month(waktu_kerusakan) BETWEEN 1 and 6 Order By jumlah_repair Desc
```

then, i try in Laravel Syntax like this below (not work) :

```php
    $sql = Main::groupBy('workcenter')->select('workcenter', \DB::raw('count(*) as frekuensi'))
                ->whereYear('waktu_kerusakan', 'like',  "%".$tahun."%")
                ->OrderBy('frekuensi', 'Desc')
                ->groupBy(\DB::raw("MONTH(waktu_kerusakan)"), [1, 6])
                ->get();
```

**Please anyone help me to convert the MySQL query to Laravel Syntax. Thank you!**

Comment: What php error does it generate? BTW spelling is "Syntax"

Comment: it doesn't show any error, but not working like the MySQL Query syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
    $repair = DB::table('repair')
    ->select('waktu_kerusakan','workcenter', DB::raw('COUNT(workcenter) AS jumlah_repair'))
->whereYear('waktu_kerusakan', $tahun)
    ->groupBy(DB::raw("MONTH(waktu_kerusakan)"), 'workcenter')
  ->whereIn(DB::raw('MONTH("waktu_kerusakan")'),[1, 6])
    ->orderBy('frekuensi', 'DESC')
    ->get()
```

Comment: hmm, by the way sir, where is the Between (in mysql : "BETWEEN 1 and 6 Order By jumlah_repair Desc" ?

Comment: Error :

Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42000)
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055
'db_portal.repair.waktu_kerusakan' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `waktu_kerusakan`, `workcenter`, count(workcenter) as frekuensi from `repair` where year(`waktu_kerusakan`) like %2019% and MONTH("waktu_kerusakan") in (1, 6) group by MONTH(waktu_kerusakan), `workcenter` order by `frekuensi` desc)

Comment: @MuhammadRobbiZulfikar please try again

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
$sql = Main::select('workcenter', \DB::raw('count(*) as frekuensi'),\DB::raw('MONTH(waktu_kerusakan) as waktu_kerusakan_month'))
            ->where('waktu_kerusakan',$tahun)
            ->whereBetween('waktu_kerusakan_month',[1, 6])
            ->groupBy('workcenter','waktu_kerusakan_month')
            ->OrderBy('jumlah_repair', 'Desc')
            ->get();
```